# Migrate builder to Spring hateoas 2.6.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have this old code implemented in hateoas:1.0

```
  public class StaticPathLinkBuilder extends LinkBuilderSupport<StaticPathLinkBuilder> {

  @Override
  protected StaticPathLinkBuilder createNewInstance(UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    return new StaticPathLinkBuilder(builder);
  }
```

I updated my code to hateoas 2.6.7 but the code is changed this way:

```
public class StaticPathLinkBuilder extends LinkBuilderSupport<StaticPathLinkBuilder> {

@Override
  protected StaticPathLinkBuilder createNewInstance(UriComponents components, List<Affordance> affordances) {
    return null;
  }
```

What is the proper way to implement this change? I tried this:

```
  @Override
  protected StaticPathLinkBuilder createNewInstance(UriComponents components, List<Affordance> affordances) {
    return new StaticPathLinkBuilder(UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().uriComponents(components));
  }
```

But it's not clear how I have to implement the code that I can send `affordances`.

Can you advice what is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in its source code `LinkBuilderSupport` already provides a [constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/19c2480f48ffeed1dd86befa8c80287a7fcc86dd/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/server/core/LinkBuilderSupport.java#L62-L71) with the two required arguments, `UriComponents` and `List<Affordance>`.

In the own library codebase, different `LinkBuilder`s implementations as [`BasicLinkBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/7a17be558a77b158e7a4c6a40a5e5609fffd91f8/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/BasicLinkBuilder.java) or  [`TemplateVariableAwareLinkBuilderSupport`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/7a17be558a77b158e7a4c6a40a5e5609fffd91f8/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/server/core/TemplateVariableAwareLinkBuilderSupport.java) already takes advantage of this fact in their implementations.

In your use case, you could try something similar to this:

```java
public class StaticPathLinkBuilder extends LinkBuilderSupport<StaticPathLinkBuilder> {

  private StaticPathLinkBuilder(UriComponents components, List<Affordance> affordances) {
    super(components, affordances);
  }

  @Override
  protected StaticPathLinkBuilder createNewInstance(UriComponents components, List<Affordance> affordances) {
    return new StaticPathLinkBuilder(components, affordances);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question that I'm stucked with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324164/replace-deprecated-invocationrecordingmethodinterceptor Can you give some advise please?