# Replace deprecated InvocationRecordingMethodInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I have this old hateos code which I would like to migrate to latest Spring hateos version

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils;

public LinkBuilder linkTo(Object dummyInvocation) {
    if (!(dummyInvocation instanceof DummyInvocationUtils.InvocationRecordingMethodInterceptor)) {
      IllegalArgumentException cause =
          new IllegalArgumentException("linkTo(Object) must be call with a dummyInvocation");
      throw InternalErrorException.builder()
          .cause(cause)
          .build();
    }
    DummyInvocationUtils.LastInvocationAware lastInvocationAware =
        (DummyInvocationUtils.LastInvocationAware) dummyInvocation;

    DummyInvocationUtils.MethodInvocation methodInvocation = lastInvocationAware.getLastInvocation();

    StaticPathLinkBuilder staticPathLinkBuilder = getThis();
    return staticPathLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodInvocation.getMethod(), methodInvocation.getArguments());
  }
```

I can't find how to replace `InvocationRecordingMethodInterceptor`, `LastInvocationAware` and `MethodInvocation` in order to use the latest version of hateos. Can you give me advise how to fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/833), the structure of packages of Spring HATEOAS was heavily refactored.

In the specific case of `DummyInvocationsUtils` it was [migrated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/commit/57f36a58db07afeb7a020c1b607e23aa2aa05008#diff-4be9d7c82464ad4064096ac40ff3e6adcda7a678561d08c7f3ca8929f234fb05) from `org.springframework.hateoas.core` to the `org.springframework.hateoas.server.core` package.

For using the new version update your import in consequence:

```java
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DummyInvocationUtils;
```

Please, be aware that both `LastInvocationAware` and `MethodInvocation` are defined in their own class files, in the same package as `DummyInvocationUtils`.

Your final code could be like this:

```java
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DummyInvocationUtils;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.LastInvocationAware;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.MethodInvocation;

//...

public LinkBuilder linkTo(Object dummyInvocation) {
    if (!(dummyInvocation instanceof LastInvocationAware)) {
      IllegalArgumentException cause =
          new IllegalArgumentException("linkTo(Object) must be call with a dummyInvocation");
      throw InternalErrorException.builder()
          .cause(cause)
          .build();
    }

    LastInvocationAware lastInvocationAware =
        (LastInvocationAware) dummyInvocation;

    MethodInvocation methodInvocation = lastInvocationAware.getLastInvocation();

    StaticPathLinkBuilder staticPathLinkBuilder = getThis();
    return staticPathLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodInvocation.getMethod(), methodInvocation.getArguments());
}
```

Comment: Correct but I get error `Cannot resolve symbol 'LastInvocationAware'` after the new import.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Peter. I updated my answer. Please, could you try the suggested changes? I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I added the imports but now I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'LastInvocationAware'` Do you know how I can  edit the code after both `LastInvocationAware` and `MethodInvocation` are defined in their own class files?